# How to Place a Text Below the Image file in the App-Bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, android-appbarlayout, flutter-appbar

I have an App-Bar , where i need to place an Text below the Image in the App-Bar. The text should align directly below the below. I have tried many ways but i cannot find a way to do it. [Image of the Output i am getting now][1]

```
      appBar:
      new PreferredSize(
       preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(240.0), 
        child: new AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Row(),
            flexibleSpace: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [reddish, blushish],
                ),
              ),
            ),

      bottom: new PreferredSize(
          child: new Container(
            child: new Image.asset('assets/rewahub_icon.png'),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80.0),
           ),
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100.0)),
      ),
      ),

I am not able to place a text below the Png file that is image file. I would like to place a text below the Image file. Please do help me with this.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P45ya.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your image in a column and add a text widget in this column.

```
                    child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Image.asset('assets/rewahub_icon.png'),
                    Text('I got my text here'),
                  ],
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can but all widgets you want to start at the same align in a column
and use MainAxisAlignment property like: `MainAxisAlignment.start`

you can use padding if you want some spaces around too ..

Comment: Hi Salah , thanks for the reply. Sorry but i didn't understood the concept you just mentioned. Can you please provide an example code for me to refer.

Comment: i,e : Column(mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignmentstart,children<widget>[Imageasset(""),Text("")]